# Measuring time of different sort methods

Tags: java, sorting, user-interface

I am writing code that is supposed to measure different sort times for different sort methods with arrays of a specific size and display the output time in a GUI.  I have got it working for the most part but the program is not displaying the same result each time.  For instance, it will say 0.2 milliseconds for one run and 0.1 for the next.  I believe the problem is in the runSort() method.  Could anybody help me?  Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Benchmarks extends JFrame
{
  private static int numberOfRuns = 20;

  private JTextField arraySizeInput, display;
  private String sortMethodNames[] =
  {"Selection Sort", "Insertion Sort", "Mergesort", "Quicksort", "Arrays.sort"};
  private JComboBox chooseSortMethod;

  private final long seed;
  private int arraySize;

// Constructor
   public Benchmarks()
  {

     super("Benchmarks");

     Container c = getContentPane();
     c.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 1));

     c.add(new JLabel(" Array size: "));
     arraySizeInput = new JTextField(4);
     arraySizeInput.setText("1000");
     arraySizeInput.selectAll();
     c.add(arraySizeInput);

     chooseSortMethod = new JComboBox(sortMethodNames);
     c.add(chooseSortMethod);

     JButton run = new JButton("Run");
     run.addActionListener(new RunButtonListener());
     c.add(run);

     c.add(new JLabel(" Avg Time (milliseconds): "));

     display = new JTextField("   Ready");
     display.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
     display.setEditable(false);
     c.add(display);

  // Use the same random number generator seed for all benchmarks
  //   in one run of this program:

     seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
  }

// Fills a[] with random numbers and sorts it using the sorting method
// specified in sortMethod:
//     1 -- Selection Sort
//     2 -- Insertion Sort
//     3 -- Mergesort
//     4 -- Quicksort
// This is repeated numberOfRuns times for better accuracy
// Returns the total time it took in milliseconds.
   private long runSort(double[] a, int sortMethod, int numberOfRuns)
  {
     long startTime;
     long endTime;
     long diffTime;  
     Random generator = new Random(seed);
     for(int i= a.length-1; i>0; i--)
     {
        a[i]= generator.nextDouble(); 
     }
     startTime= System.currentTimeMillis();

     switch(sortMethod) 
     {  
        case 1: //Selection Sort
           SelectionSort sel = new SelectionSort(); 
           sel.sort(a);
           break; 
        case 2: //Insertion Sort 
           InsertionSort nsert= new InsertionSort();
           nsert.sort(a); 
           break; 
        case 3: //Merge Sort 
           Mergesort merge = new Mergesort(); 
           merge.sort(a); 
           break; 
        case 4: // Quick Sort 
           Quicksort quick = new Quicksort();
           quick.sort(a); 
           break; 
     }
     endTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
     diffTime= endTime- startTime; 


     return  diffTime ;  
  }

// Handles Run button events
   private class RunButtonListener implements ActionListener
  {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
     {
        String inputStr = arraySizeInput.getText().trim();
        try
        {
           arraySize = Integer.parseInt(inputStr);
        }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex)
           {
              display.setText(" Invalid array size");
              arraySize = 0;
              return;
           }  

        if (arraySize <= 0)
        {
           display.setText(" Invalid array size");
           return;
        }

        if (arraySize <= 0)
           return;

        int sortMethod = chooseSortMethod.getSelectedIndex() + 1;
        double a[] = new double[arraySize];
        double avgTime = (double)runSort(a, sortMethod, numberOfRuns)
                                                      / numberOfRuns;
        display.setText(String.format("  %.2f", avgTime));

        arraySizeInput.selectAll();
        arraySizeInput.requestFocus();
        System.out.println("Array size = " + arraySize +
           " Runs = " + numberOfRuns + " " +
           sortMethodNames[sortMethod - 1] + " avg time: " + avgTime);

     }
  }

//************************************************************

   public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     numberOfRuns = 20;
     if (args.length > 0)
     {
        int n = -1;
        try
        {
           n = Integer.parseInt(args[0].trim());
        }
            catch (NumberFormatException ex)
           {
              System.out.println("Invalid command-line parameter");
              System.exit(1);
           }
        if (n > 0)
           numberOfRuns = n;
     }

     Benchmarks window = new Benchmarks();
     window.setBounds(300, 300, 180, 200);
     window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why do you expect your code to produce identical time-based results each time? The times can vary by quite a bit, depending on countless factors. That's why measuring an algorithm's performance by time is rarely done. Instead, learn to use and then factor in time-complexity using big-O notation. There are many resources online to study up on this, and every introduction to algorithms book will have a chapter dedicated to this topic.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit more?  If there is an array of size 1000, shouldn't the sorting time be the same each time if the data in the array is the same?

Comment: @skateboard34 such short measurements fall in the micro benchmarks category - and [they are notoriously difficult to measure accurately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: The "simple" solution would be: Make the array larger, and perform the sorting operation serveral times (each time with a new array). This will flatten out the lack of accuracy for smaller time spans, and **although the timing results still have to be taken with a huge grain of salt** you will at least be able to quickly see the difference between an O(nlogn) and an O(n*n) algorithm

Comment: For short execution times, use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting different results because of many minor factors, like how busy the computer is at the time. Also, `System.currentTimeMillis()` is inherently inaccurate; on some systems, 5 ms may be measured as 0 to 10 ms. To get better accuracy when measuring small amounts of time, you should use [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime--). Also, you should have *nothing at all* between measuring the start time and measuring the end time. That means *no* for or while loops, if statements, or switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

What you try is simply not possible. You'll need a system with garanteed cpu time. But scheduling and different loads makes it impossible to get exact times. Additional the Java-Garbage collection and things like optimizing from the java enviroment changes your results. you could use a framework like [junitbenchmark](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/junit-benchmarks.html) and let the code run multible times - but rembemer this will not give you a "really usable" result. It can help you to determ the speed of each algorithm in relation to each other.